# How to use Fico Xpress (Mosel) with Java?

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming, mosel, xpress-optimizer

I have created an optimization model with Xpress and now I want to access it via my Java code.
On the official Xpress Help page (https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/dms2019-01/mosel/UG/dhtml/moselugC2_sec_secc2java.html) it said to use
`import com.dashoptimization.*;` but from my understanding of Java imports, to do so I would need the dashoptimization.jar file. Also, Eclipse says the import can not be resolved.
But where can I find the dashoptimization.jar file to add to my project? I looked online and could not find it. Or is something else wrong with the import?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.dashoptimization` classes are in files like `xprs.jar` in the `xpressmp/lib/` directory.